# Qt - Why can't I trigger mousePressEvent for my custom button in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

This is my first time to ask on Stack Overflow. If any suggestion about asking question, please let me know.
I am very new to Qt, and have some problems while using event. Hope someone can provide any thoughts.

**Background:**

I have my custom pushButton, which is `rxPushButton` in `rx.h` and `rx.cpp`. I use `on_rxPushButton_clicked` to change the image and it works pretty well.
In `MainWindow`, I need to use some `rx` so I include the class `rx` and I want to detect if I press left button of the mouse, I need to know which `rx` has been pressed and record its id in `int` `rxId` in `MainWindow`.

**Problem:**

I tried two ways to achieve my goal, including `mousePressEvent` and `eventFilter`. I found that I can't detect the mouse pressed signal on any `rx`, but I can detect it outside `rx` in other places in `Mainwindow`. I wonder if the events will conflict, but when I comment `on_rxPushButton_clicked` in `rx.cpp`, `MainWindow` still doesn't work for the problem. So I presume that maybe the space in the screen occupied by `rx` will not be in control of `MainWindow` (I can get Debug message "test1" but not "test2" in my code, check below).
How should I do to solve this problem if I need both things (change image in `rx` and modify one variable in `MainWindow`)? Or maybe it's just something wrong with my code and how to modify?

I hope to separate them if possible because I still need to include many objects in `MainWindow` in the future.

Here are some of my related codes:

rx.cpp

```
void rx::on_rxPushButton_clicked(void)
{
    startLoading();
}

void rx::startLoading(void)
{
    state = 1;
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(loading1()));
    timer->start(LOADING_INTERVAL);
}

void rx::loading1(void)
{
    if(state == 1)
    {
        state = 2;
        ui->rxPushButton->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/images/Rx/Rxloading1.png);");
        disconnect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(loading1()));
    }
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < rxSize ; i++)
    {
        rxList << new rx(this);
        int j = i/rxHorizontalCount;
        rxList[i]->setGeometry(500+(i-j*8)*110,10+j*90,100,90);
    }
    //rxList[0]->installEventFilter(this);
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        qDebug() << "test1";
        if(rxList[0]->rect().contains(event->x(), event->y()))
            qDebug() << "test2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary; welcome to SO and thanks for this post! I attempted to put in an edit fixing a few minor points but unfortunately your edit bumped my own and now the edit queue is fully. However, I wanted to take the time to thank you for a detailed and well explained post and hope you will make more posts on Stack Overflow in the future. One small point to bear in mind is to try to include backticks around variable names and functions within your main text as it aids readability.

Comment: `MainWindow::eventFilter` & `installEventFilter` should work. Can you share your code of `eventFilter`?

Comment: Note that the problem is that each event is normally handled by one event handler. This is in most cases the desired behavior. You can explicitly [`ignore`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#ignore) an event to let it propagate to its parent.

Comment: "The rect property equals QRect(0, 0, width(), height())" - from QWidget docummentation. May be I'm getting it wrong with my poor english, but it seems to me you should modify your code checking whether rx's rect contains event's position.

Comment: Why are you trying to intercept the mouse event this way rather than simply connecting to the [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal emitted by the `rxPushButton`?

Comment: Could you share all code? Without it is hard to give you best solution.

Comment: @YuriyPryyma I would insist sharing only a [mcve]. I makes your question easier to understand and it will make your question much more interesting for other users with the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change image in rx**

Use QSignalMapper class  that bundles signals from QWidgets (class rx) and re-emits them with widget (class rx) parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal.
We connect each button's clicked() signal to the signal mapper's map() slot, and create a mapping in the signal mapper from each button to the button itself. 
Finally we connect the signal mapper's mapped() signal to the custom widget's(rx object) clicked() signal. When the user clicks a button, the custom widget(rx object) will emit a single clicked() signal whose argument is the button (rx object) the user clicked.
Handle the button clicked event in MainWindow::slotButtonsClicked(QWidget *p) function.

**Modify n variable in MainWindow:**

You can update variable of MainWindow in mousePressEvent function

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget
   {
    public :
        MainWindow (QWidget *parent);

        QSignalMapper * mapper;

    slots:
        void slotButtonsClicked(QWidget *);

    // ...  
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < rxSize ; i++)
    {
        rxList << new rx(this);
        int j = i/rxHorizontalCount;
        rxList[i]->setGeometry(500+(i-j*8)*110,10+j*90,100,90);
        QObject::connect(rxList[i], SIGNAL(clicked()),mapper,SLOT(map()));

        //Adds a mapping so that when map() is signalled from the sender, the signal mapped(widget ) is emitted.
        mapper->setMapping(rxList[i], rxList[i]);
    }

    QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget *)),this,SLOT(slotButtonsClicked(QWidget *)));   
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        qDebug() << "Clicked outside the button";

        //Now you can modify n variable in MainWindow
    }

    MainWindow::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void MainWindow::slotButtonsClicked(QWidget *p)
{
    rx *button = dynamic_cast<rx *>(p);
    button->on_rxPushButton_clicked();

    qDebug() << button <<" clicked on button";

    //Now you can change image in rx 
}
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
After some trials and errors, I think QSignalMapper is the thing I need!

Answer (score 0):

Event propagating prevent you to do it. When mouse is over Button, event sends to button, not to the MainWindow, thats why you never see test2 in debug output.

Since I don't know what do you need it's hard to say what you should do. You can process event in Button and send some signals or whatever, or set event filter and check if target object is your button, and so on.

Any way, read [Qt event system docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) for better understanding.